# a2ensite fudging supplied path

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

When trying to a2ensite my new virtual host, I'm receiving an error indicating that the virtual host config isn't there, when the path I specified does in fact exist.  The a2ensite command seems to be ignoring the 'conf' suffix on my path.  Why?

```
webdev@staging01:~$ sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com.conf
ERROR: Site /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com does not exist!

webdev@staging01:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  226 Jul 21 11:07 test.x.com.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a2ensite` does not expect the full path as its argument. Try

```
sudo a2ensite test.x.com.conf
```

As an aside, the `.conf` extension is not customary with vhost definition files. That's up to you, though.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  a2ensite seems to want either text.x.com, or test.x.com.conf, as long as it doesn't get the full path it's happy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an error suggesting that `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com` "does not exists, not `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com.conf`. You have a reference for `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com` inside of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.x.com.conf`.